# ISNUMBER() validation rule for numbers

Tags: validation, salesforce, isnumeric

I am trying to add a new validation rule `ISNUMBER(number)` on a number type field.

but it seems like I can't because I got a syntax error, `Error: Incorrect argument type for function 'ISNUMBER()'`

How could I validate this field and check if it's a number ?

Answer (score 2):

Formula ISNUMBER() checks if the entered text number or not. So we can not use a number as an argument of this formula, only text.